# Declaring parameters does not work if anything is above param

Tags: function, powershell, variables, parameters

I have a script with parameters. In order to ease the debug of the script I create a small function I found on the net to list all my variables. In order to do so, I start by getting all existing variables at the top of the script, then I create a function which compares recorded variables before and after getting parameters

Problem is when I put the `$AutomaticVariables` and the function before `param` declaration, PowerShell gives me the following error for any parameter where I set a default value. Is there anyway to workaround this … bug? If it's not a bug, why the hell this behavior. I don't see the point.

> The assignment expression is not valid. The input to an assignment operator must be an object that is able to accept assignments, such as a 
>   variable or a property.

```
# Array and function to debug script variable content
$AutomaticVariables = Get-Variable

function check_variables {
  Compare-Object (Get-Variable) $AutomaticVariables -Property Name -PassThru |
    Where -Property Name -ne "AutomaticVariables"
}

param(
  [String]$hostname,
  [String]$jobdesc,
  [String]$type = "standard",
  [String]$repo,
  [String]$ocred,
  [String]$site,
  [String]$cred = "SRC-$($site)-adm",
  [String]$sitetype,
  [String]$room,
  [String]$chsite = "chub"
)

# TEST - Display variables
check_variables
```

Comment: Should I say that even if I put a simple variable declaration as stupid as x=1 before param, behavior is the same. So it's not related to Get-Variable or to the function. Anything before param give the same result.

Comment: It's not a bug, that's just how the language is designed in order to make life easier for whoever writes the parser.

Comment: How then to handle variables I want to set before parameters ? 

I tried to add Get-Variable Inside parameters, but it contains then all other param variables. It seems not to be set in order.

Comment: You'll have to set those in the calling scope (ie. outside the script)

Comment: Can you describe in more detail the purpose/kind of debugging you're trying to do? What kind/class of problem would you attempt to debug using this technique?

Comment: My purpose is simply to list my variables content to see what it is.

Just like Get-Variable does, but without automatic variables shown

Comment: Why do you think you need to do that before the parameter definitions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you should gather the variables you want to exclude in the calling scope:

Define function (could as well be a script), notice the `$DebugFunc` parameter I've added at the end:

```
function Do-Stuff 
{
    param(
        [String]$hostname,
        [String]$jobdesc,
        [String]$type = "standard",
        [String]$repo,
        [String]$ocred,
        [String]$site,
        [String]$cred = "SRC-$($site)-adm",
        [String]$sitetype,
        [String]$room,
        [String]$chsite = "chub",
        [scriptblock]$DebugFunc
    )

    if($PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('DebugFunc')){
        . $DebugFunc
    }
}
```

Now, gather the variables and define your function, then inject it into `Do-Stuff`:

```
# Array and function to debug script variable content
$AutomaticVariables = Get-Variable
function check_variables {
    Compare-Object (Get-Variable) $AutomaticVariables -Property Name -PassThru | Where -Property Name -ne "AutomaticVariables"
}

Do-Stuff -DebugFunc $Function:check_variables
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not a bug. The *param* section defines the input parameter of your script thus has to be the first statement (same as with functions). There is **no need to perform any action before the param block**.

If you explain what you want to achieve with your `check_variables` (not what it does). We probably can show you how to do it right.

Comment: My purpose is simply to list my variables content to see what it is. Just like Get-Variable does, but without automatic variables shown